What is the CMLL Algorithm that fits this particular case?
I implemented the CFOP method in my Rubik's cube solver. Now I am trying to add the Roux method. I couldn't find the right CMLL algorithm for this particular case.
After consulting the CMLL algorithms in SpeedCubeDB.com, I could narrow down the potential algorithm to be one of the Sune/Anti-Sune cases.
What is the right CMLL algorithm for this case? Why?


For a moment I thought that I could pan and rotate the cube with the mouse ...

From that page it's the Sune Up Slash.

Here is how the Sune/Anti-sune cases (i.e. those with one correctly oriented corner) are recognised/categorised:

Rotate the cube or last layer so that the single correctly oriented corner is at the front, and the other front corner has its U-coloured facelet to the side (i.e. no U colour on the front face).
Look at the four facelets marked with a dot in the above picture, i.e. the two front facelets of the front corners and the top facelets of the rear corners. These are visible in a single glance without needing to tilt or turn the cube.
Consider which of the four facelets form matching colour pairs. In this case it is the front left and back right, i.e. like a / slash. Each case has a unique configuration of one or two matching pairs, and the name describes their shape.

